# Draw simulation from top to bottom instead of from center to border

Tags: d3.js

Below graph draw nodes from center to border, how can I modify it to draw nodes from top to bottom?

```js
function drawGraph(graph) {
    const width = "800";
    const height = "800";
    const sourceRadius = 25;
    const entityRadius = 25;

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody()
               .strength(-600)
               .theta(1)
               .distanceMax(400)
                            )
        .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
            return d.radius
        }))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));//document.querySelector("#networkGraph").clientHeight

    var defs = svg.append("defs");
    defs.append("radialGradient")
        .attr("id", "entity-gradient")
        .attr("cx", "50%") 
        .attr("cy", "50%") 
        .attr("r", "50%") 
        .selectAll("stop")
        .data([
            {offset: "50%", color: "#ffffff"},
            {offset: "100%", color: "#CCCCCC"},
        ])
        .enter().append("stop")
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });

    defs.append("radialGradient")
        .attr("id", "source-gradient")
        .selectAll("stop")
        .data([
            {offset: "20%", color: "#eda515"},
            {offset: "100%", color: "#827777"},
        ])
        .enter().append("stop")
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });

    var link = svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")

    link
        .style("stroke", "#aaa");

    var node = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
    //I made the article/source nodes larger than attribute nodes
                .attr("r", function(d){return d.category==0 ? sourceRadius : entityRadius});

    node
        .style("fill", "#cccccc")
        .style("fill-opacity","0.9")
        .style("stroke", "#424242")
        .style("stroke-width", "1px");

    node
        .style("fill", function(d){return d.category==0 ? "url(#source-gradient)" : "url(#entity-gradient)"});

    var label = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "labels")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("text")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .attr("class", "label");
    
    label
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-size", function(d) {
                        var r = 10
                        if (d.category == 1) {
                                r = Math.min(2 * entityRadius, (2 * entityRadius - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 15) + "px"
                        }else {
                                r = Math.min(2 * sourceRadius, (2 * sourceRadius - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 15) + "px"
                        }
                        return r/2;
                });

    label 
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            tooltip.html(`${d.name}`); 
            return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
        .on("mousemove", function(event,d){
            return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})

    node
        .on("mouseover", function(event,d){
            tooltip.html(`${d.name}`); 
            return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
        .on("mousemove", function(event,d){
            return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(event.pageX+10)+"px");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");});
    
    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
        .links(graph.links);

    function ticked() {
        link
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x+5; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y-3; });
        
        label
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y; });

    }

    var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .style("color", "white")
        .style("padding", "8px")
        .style("background-color", "#626D71")
        .style("border-radius", "6px")
        .style("text-align", "center")
        .style("width", "auto")
        .text("");        
}

var data = {
        "nodes":[
                {"id": "999", "name": "O", "count": 0, "category": 0},              
                {"id": "000", "name": "A", "count": 0, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "001", "name": "B", "count": 1, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "002", "name": "C", "count": 1, "category": 1},
                {"id": "003", "name": "D", "count": 0, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "004", "name": "E", "count": 1, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "005", "name": "F", "count": 1, "category": 1},
                {"id": "006", "name": "G", "count": 0, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "007", "name": "H", "count": 1, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "008", "name": "I", "count": 1, "category": 1},
                {"id": "009", "name": "J", "count": 0, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "010", "name": "K", "count": 1, "category": 1}, 
                {"id": "011", "name": "L", "count": 1, "category": 1},
                {"id": "100", "name": "M", "count": 0, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "101", "name": "N", "count": 1, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "102", "name": "O", "count": 1, "category": 2},
                {"id": "103", "name": "P", "count": 0, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "104", "name": "Q", "count": 1, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "105", "name": "R", "count": 1, "category": 2},
                {"id": "106", "name": "S", "count": 0, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "107", "name": "T", "count": 1, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "108", "name": "U", "count": 1, "category": 2},
                {"id": "109", "name": "V", "count": 0, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "110", "name": "W", "count": 1, "category": 2}, 
                {"id": "111", "name": "X", "count": 1, "category": 2}],
        "links":[
                {"source": "000", "target": "100", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "001", "target": "101", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "002", "target": "102", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "003", "target": "103", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "004", "target": "104", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "005", "target": "105", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "006", "target": "106", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "007", "target": "107", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "008", "target": "108", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "009", "target": "109", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "010", "target": "110", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "011", "target": "111", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "999", "target": "000", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "999", "target": "001", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "999", "target": "002", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "999", "target": "003", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "999", "target": "004", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "999", "target": "005", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "999", "target": "006", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "999", "target": "007", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "999", "target": "008", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "999", "target": "009", "value": 1, "count": 1},
                {"source": "999", "target": "010", "value": 1, "count": 1}, 
                {"source": "999", "target": "011", "value": 1, "count": 1}]
}

drawGraph(data)
/*d3.json(graphUrl).then(function(data){
    blogGraph(data)
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is creating a point scale and using `forceY` to set the vertical position based on the `category` property:

```
.force('yPos', d3.forceY(d => scale(d.category)).strength(1))
```

Here I'm hardcoding the scale values for brevity, but calculating them is trivial. This is your code with those changes:

```js
function drawGraph(graph) {
  const width = "800";
  const height = "800";
  const sourceRadius = 25;
  const entityRadius = 25;

  const scale = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([100, 700])
    .domain([0, 1, 2]);

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody()
      .strength(-600)
      .theta(1)
      .distanceMax(400)
    )
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
      return d.radius
    }))
    .force('yPos', d3.forceY(d => scale(d.category)).strength(1))
    .force('xPos', d3.forceX(400))
  //.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));//document.querySelector("#networkGraph").clientHeight

  var defs = svg.append("defs");
  defs.append("radialGradient")
    .attr("id", "entity-gradient")
    .attr("cx", "50%")
    .attr("cy", "50%")
    .attr("r", "50%")
    .selectAll("stop")
    .data([{
        offset: "50%",
        color: "#ffffff"
      },
      {
        offset: "100%",
        color: "#CCCCCC"
      },
    ])
    .enter().append("stop")
    .attr("offset", function(d) {
      return d.offset;
    })
    .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    });

  defs.append("radialGradient")
    .attr("id", "source-gradient")
    .selectAll("stop")
    .data([{
        offset: "20%",
        color: "#eda515"
      },
      {
        offset: "100%",
        color: "#827777"
      },
    ])
    .enter().append("stop")
    .attr("offset", function(d) {
      return d.offset;
    })
    .attr("stop-color", function(d) {
      return d.color;
    });

  var link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")

  link
    .style("stroke", "#aaa");

  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    //I made the article/source nodes larger than attribute nodes
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.category == 0 ? sourceRadius : entityRadius
    });

  node
    .style("fill", "#cccccc")
    .style("fill-opacity", "0.9")
    .style("stroke", "#424242")
    .style("stroke-width", "1px");

  node
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.category == 0 ? "url(#source-gradient)" : "url(#entity-gradient)"
    });

  var label = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .attr("class", "label");

  label
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("font-size", function(d) {
      var r = 10
      if (d.category == 1) {
        r = Math.min(2 * entityRadius, (2 * entityRadius - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 15) + "px"
      } else {
        r = Math.min(2 * sourceRadius, (2 * sourceRadius - 8) / this.getComputedTextLength() * 15) + "px"
      }
      return r / 2;
    });

  label
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      tooltip.html(`${d.name}`);
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(event, d) {
      return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
    })

  node
    .on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
      tooltip.html(`${d.name}`);
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
    })
    .on("mousemove", function(event, d) {
      return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (event.pageX + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x + 5;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y - 3;
      });

    label
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });

  }

  var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")
    .style("color", "white")
    .style("padding", "8px")
    .style("background-color", "#626D71")
    .style("border-radius", "6px")
    .style("text-align", "center")
    .style("width", "auto")
    .text("");
}

var data = {
  "nodes": [{
      "id": "999",
      "name": "O",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "000",
      "name": "A",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "001",
      "name": "B",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "002",
      "name": "C",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "003",
      "name": "D",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "004",
      "name": "E",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "005",
      "name": "F",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "006",
      "name": "G",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "007",
      "name": "H",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "008",
      "name": "I",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "009",
      "name": "J",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "010",
      "name": "K",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "011",
      "name": "L",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "100",
      "name": "M",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "101",
      "name": "N",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "102",
      "name": "O",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "103",
      "name": "P",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "104",
      "name": "Q",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "105",
      "name": "R",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "106",
      "name": "S",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "107",
      "name": "T",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "108",
      "name": "U",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "109",
      "name": "V",
      "count": 0,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "110",
      "name": "W",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    },
    {
      "id": "111",
      "name": "X",
      "count": 1,
      "category": 2
    }
  ],
  "links": [{
      "source": "000",
      "target": "100",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "001",
      "target": "101",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "002",
      "target": "102",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "003",
      "target": "103",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "004",
      "target": "104",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "005",
      "target": "105",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "006",
      "target": "106",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "007",
      "target": "107",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "008",
      "target": "108",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "009",
      "target": "109",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "010",
      "target": "110",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "011",
      "target": "111",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "000",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "001",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "002",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "003",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "004",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "005",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "006",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "007",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "008",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "009",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "010",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "source": "999",
      "target": "011",
      "value": 1,
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}

drawGraph(data)
/*d3.json(graphUrl).then(function(data){
    blogGraph(data)
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
```